# How to use proxies library in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, proxy

I want to create an Android app that connects to a proxy by button clicked and I'd like to know what should do to make this event?

My proxy needs(password, username, host, port).

I would be appreciated if you help me with this problem .

Comment: I'm looking for the same. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In your flutter app you need to use [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) http client - this answer is written as version `5.3.2`.

Button should call function that will update existing HTTP Dio client like so:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:dio/io.dart';

void setupProxy(Dio httpClient) {
  //enter your data here:
  final ipAddress = '192.168.0.8';
  final port = '8888';
  final credentials = HttpClientBasicCredentials('username', 'password');


  httpClient.httpClientAdapater = IOHttpClientAdapter(
    createHttpClient: () {
      return HttpClient()
        ..badCertificateCallback = (cert, host, port) => true
        ..addProxyCredentials(ipAddress, port, 'main', credentials)
        ..findProxy = ((uri) => 'PROXY $ipAddress:$port');
    },
  );
}
```

When you run your app and tap button you should be able to intercept and monitor your HTTP traffic using [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io/) or [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/). Their documentation will help you setup device with your app.

Answer (score 0):

Add DIO settings like this

```
String proxy = '<IP>:<PORT>'; //eg 192.168.1.1:8080
var credentials = HttpClientBasicCredentials(<USERNAME>, <PASSWORD>);
bool isProxyChecked = true;

(dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate = 
(client) {
  client.badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
    return isProxyChecked && Platform.isAndroid;
  };
  client.findProxy = (url) {
    return isProxyChecked ? 'PROXY $proxy' : 'DIRECT';
  };

  client.addProxyCredentials(<PROXY_IP>, <PORT>, 'main', credentials);

};
```